# What's the correct object-oriented way to define something in multiple ways?

Tags: oop

I'd like to clarify in advance that this is NOT a techincal, but an ideological question. I can think of billions of workarounds, but I'd like to learn a way that would satisfy the OOP paradigm the most. Now, the question itself:

Say, for instance, that I have two methods in a class, where each one may be defined on its own or utilising the other one (and, let us assume, that a recursive case would go infinite). Defining both on their own would mean having duplicate code. I could, of course, choose one as the basic one and reference it in the other one, but if such relation isn't explicitly derived from the specifications, this could lead to issues upon further development and expansion, etc.

The best solution I can think of is somehow separating the common part into a different method, but I can't tell if that would cause further problems or not.

In general, if we leave aside the specific example, Object-Orientedness, as I understand it, allows me to define abstractions through other abstractions, but only in a strict tree-like hierarchy (+multiple inheritance, but that still doesn't cover everything). In some cases, however, an abstraction can be defined in several different ways through different sets of other abstractions, and I'd like to learn how to implement that in practice.

For code examples, if you wish to give those, I'd prefer you to use python (as it features the widest support for object-orientedness among languages known to me), but in the end, anything is fine, as long as it's not something like haskell (a.k.a. not object-oriented at all), or javascipt (where the language itself doesn't respect standards and uniformity).

Thank you in advance, and sorry for any possible English-related mistakes

Comment: I think if you provide a simple code piece it would be a lot easier to understand the actual issue.

Comment: A code sample would unreasonably narrow down the set of possible cases where this could appear and tempt people to answer the code, not the abstract issue, so I'd like to keep it mostly theoretical